# To how many decimal places should the margin be defined? Strategy()

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Here's a `strategy()` code when Leverage is 100:

```
strategy("Brute Strategy", margin_long=100, margin_short=100, overlay=true, initial_capital = 20, default_qty_value = 500, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity)
```

It's okay. But what if Leverage is 30?

```
strategy("Brute Strategy", margin_long=3.33333333, margin_short=3.33333333, overlay=true, initial_capital = 20, default_qty_value = 150, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity)
```

**We can not specify the margin ***exactly*** because it's an infinite decimal fraction. What to know about this case?**

Btw shouldn't make the code itself calculate the margin (and the `default_qty_value`)? We can't do this because `strategy()` function seems going crazy when it gets arithmetic values (`100/30` in this case) or a variable calculated earlier.